# Discord.py Raspberry Pi Threading Issue

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, raspberry-pi, discord.py

I was making a Discord bot when I decided to host it on my Raspberry pi 4B. I transferred my files, downloaded Python 3.8, did all of the necessary rituals. Then, I decided to run my bot. Everything seems fine when I just keep getting threading issues. Over and over and over again, threading, threading, threading. I get it in my on_message event, here's the code for that. It is in a cog, too. Using aiosqlite for my databases and .db file extensions if that matters.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    db = await aiosqlite.connect('aichannels.db')
    cursor = await db.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f'SELECT channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {message.channel.guild.id}')
    result = await cursor.fetchone()
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        if result is None:
            return
        else:
            if message.channel.id == result[0]:
                await message.channel.trigger_typing()
                response = await rs.get_ai_response(message.content)
                await message.reply(response)
            else:
                return
    await self.client.process_commands(message)
    await cursor.close()
    await db.close()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/ConchBot/cogs/Fun.py", line 16, in on_message
    db = await aiosqlite.connect('aichannels.db')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 146, in await
    self.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 847, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
```

also, just now, I stopped getting errors and this popped up:

```
^CSSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0xb55a3ed0>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 207, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.unwrap()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 767, in unwrap
    return self._sslobj.shutdown()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2609)
```

I'm sort of new to Raspberry Pi hosting and have no clue what this means. If anyone could help me I'd be very greatful. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an issue on a lower layer (OS, network…). The Raspberry Pi tends to get such weired troubles if it can't read the SD card properly or the voltage is insufficient. It might be a good idea to run `dmesg` on the console and check the output for errors.

Comment: What errors am I exactly looking for? I saw some red text, one which might be a problem. It reads 'brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled

Comment: What OS does the script successfully run on? I would be surprised if it were a Raspbian issue.

Comment: It runs on my Windows machine, but not on Raspbian or Ubuntu Server. I have a feeling it might have something to do with this:
'brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled' when I run dmesg.So I think it's something with my hardware, but I don't know how I could take that chip out of power save.